# Changing a keyboard's key color WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have seen other posts surrounding the subject,
but i want to change only the enter(return) key, not the whole keyboard.
Just like in the windows phone 8 store[image] 
where the enter button has a white color.

Comment: Show your codes and tell people what have you tried..

Comment: just set `InputScope="Url"` to your `TextBox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change layout of the windows phone keyboard using `InputScope` property.

Try: `<TextBox InputScope="Search" />`

You can find all available layouts here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426929(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Wow, like magic!
I'm going to get my head around that property.